# How do I make a transparent wix widget not block content behind it?

Tags: javascript, iframe, widget, velo

Im making a plugin for wix and am using the "Wix Blocks" editor, The widget has a fixed position on the screen in the bottom right. The problem is that if there is some site content behind the widget it is blocked / non interactable, so i made the widget resizable via a min / max button but it still blocks the background elements even when there seems to be nothing there.

Ive tried using wix/velo api's collapse() function on the root widget element. I was expecting it would collapse it completely but there still seems to be an invisible i frame there.

Wix's api really limits javascript functionalities, if i were able to access DOM i could easily resize the iframe itself but i can't and im not that experienced with Wix / Velo. There also are very few resources on wix plugin development.

Comment: If you don't want the widget to be interactable you can try using `pointer-events: none`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox where can i set this? and can i change it in runtime?

Comment: collapse api should work for you as it is using display:none; behind the scenes. if you still have issues you can try the new delete api that removes an element from the DOM completely. https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/box/delete